# str ops into existing Vec

Tags: string, rust, allocation

Most operations on `str` in Rust create newly-allocated `String`s. I understand that, because UTF8 is complex, one cannot generally know beforehand the size of the output, and so that output must be growable. However, I might have my own buffer , such as a `Vec<u8>` I'd like to grow. Is there any way to specify an existing output container to string operations?

e.g.,

```
let s = "my string";
let s: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(100);  // explicit allocation
s.upper_into(s);  // perhaps new allocation here, if result fits in `v`
```

-EDIT-

This is, of course, just for one case. I'd love to be able to treat all of the str methods this way, including for example those in sentencecase , without having to copy their internal logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk char-by-char and use [`char::to_uppercase()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_uppercase):

```rust
let mut uppercase = String::with_capacity(100);
uppercase.extend(s.chars().flat_map(char::to_uppercase));
```

I think it does not handle everything correctly, but [this is exactly what `str::to_uppercase()` does too](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/alloc/str.rs.html#464-481), so I assume it's OK.

Comment: Thanks, and I suppose this works. Is there no general way not to have to look inside str methods and copy out what they do? I am thinking of possibly complex operations. Note that `char::to_uppercase` ignores locale, and direct access to the internal `conversions` is disallowed with the stable build.

Comment: "Note that char::to_uppercase ignores locale" so does `str::to_uppercase`, both call the same underlying function. The stdlib has no support whatsoever for locales, and if it did I assume it would be an explicit parameter seeing how much of a clusterfuck C locales are.

Comment: "Is there no general way not to have to look inside str methods and copy out what they do?" the `[source]` link of the documentation. Or going to read the code on github directly.

Comment: It wasn't the looking but the copy I was wanting to avoid, since there are a LOT of similar methods.

Comment: Is there? I see only 7 methods of `str` which return a `String`, two of them have an in-place variant, and one can be replaced by `iter::repeat` if you want to `repeat` into an existing buffer. As Chayim noted `to_uppercase` and `to_lowercase` are mostly repeated applications of `char::to_*`. That leaves only the replacers which don't have an easy. Here I don't see a solution, I don't think even `regex` provides an iterator for that sort of things. `String` only adds one more (`String::split_off`), and that seems easy enough to replicate using `str::split` if possibly a bit less efficient.

Comment: The replace methods aren't really that complex either. The heavy lifting is done in `match_indices()` and the underlying machinery (the `MatchIndices` type and the impls of the `Pattern` trait), which are mostly publicly exposed. The main problem is that the `Pattern` trait is only available in Nightly, so you can't even write the prototype of your own `replace()` method. On Nightly, on the other hand, the implementation is quite simple – it's just `output.extend(input.split(from).intersperse(to));`.